# Notification adware on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, malware, antivirus

[image]

I remember visiting thecustomizewindows . com and clicking on some kind of pop up. I didn't install any new extensions recently, though I'm not sure exactly how I got this.

How can I get rid of this? Also any ideas to avoid such infections in the future.

> You don't need an Antivirus on Linux ... They said. Linux is 
>   invulnerable .. They said :D

Comment: Check your add-ons if anything new came in. I'm not familiar with Chrome, but that would be the first step. The next step would be to restart the browser, maybe after that logging out and in or rebooting. If it still persists, I guess you have a problem.